# Setting the Navigation String for webbrowser from another form

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to set the navigation of a webbrowser which is in a usercontrol from another form,I defined this function in the usercontrol

```
public string LoadHTML(string htmlfilepath)
{
    return htmlfilepath;
}
private void startpage()
{
    OnThisLoad();
    webBrowser1.Navigate(LoadHTML(""));
}
```

in the main form

```
htmlLoadWebbrowser1.LoadHTML(@"D:\H2.htm");
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: :Dose second form contain user control already opened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your LoadHTML function is doing what you want it to

```
public void LoadHTML(string htmlfilepath)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(htmlfilepath);
}
```

If this is so, then your other function would break

```
private void startpage()
{
    OnThisLoad();
    webBrowser1.Navigate("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I write an example for you:

I think you have 2 form with name `form1` and `form2` and `usercontrol1`

set `Modifiers` property of `web-browser` control on `usercontrol1` to `Public`.

if your user control is placed on form1 set its `Modifiers` property to `Public`
and in second form(form 2) do this:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.Show();
    frm1.userControl11.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
}
```